# UISegmentedControl Not functioning

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi im trying to use segmented control to swap between three map views however its not working.

My IBAction method is as follows.

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"inside segmented switch");
    NSLog(@"selected segment %@",selectedSegment);
    if (selectedSegment == 0) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard; 

    }
    else{
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid; 

    }
}
```

I have declared UISegementedControl as an outlet and connected it to the xib view. I have also connected this method with touch down/touch up inside/outside. It still doesn't print the NSLog commands given above. Which means this method is not accessed at all?

Comment: Yeah but right now it doesnt even go into the segmentedSwitch method. Meaning my NSLog command is not printed which means its not even in there?

Comment: Use value changed instead of touch up inside or any other event types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick summary of how to set up a UISegmentedControl in IB for those dealing with more than two segments:

1. `IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;` in @interface (or set it as @property)
2. `- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender;` in .h before @end
3. drag "Segmented Control" into view and change "Style" to Plain, Bordered, or Bar
4. increment # of "Segments"
5. Choose "Segment" and edit the "Title" making sure "Enabled" is checked
6. Connect your segmentedControl to Files Owner
7. Connect your segmentedControlIndexChanged: action and select "Value Changed" NOT "Touch up Inside"!!
8. add some code, maybe a switch statement if you have say 4 segments:

> 

```
-(IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"segmentedControlIndexChanged");

switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"dateSegmentActive");
        dateSegmentActive = YES;
        noteSegmentActive = NO;
        typeSegmentActive = NO;
        userIDSegmentActive = NO;
        [yourTable reloadData];
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        NSLog(@"noteSegmentActive");
        dateSegmentActive = NO;
        noteSegmentActive = YES;
        typeSegmentActive = NO;
        userIDSegmentActive = NO;
        [yourTable reloadData];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        NSLog(@"typeSegmentActive");
        dateSegmentActive = NO;
        noteSegmentActive = NO;
        typeSegmentActive = YES;
        userIDSegmentActive = NO;
        [yourTable reloadData];
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        NSLog(@"userIDSegmentActive");
        dateSegmentActive = NO;
        noteSegmentActive = NO;
        typeSegmentActive = NO;
        userIDSegmentActive = YES;
        [yourTable reloadData];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

In recent iOS versions, you need the braces for each case: or you will get errors.  This also shows some bool flagging to keep track of what segment is active, maybe for your willDisplayCell method.

Comment: nope. im thinking `TouchUpInside` is not an event registered with segemented controls. I tried `.AllEvents` and it doesn't work as well. My intended use is any touch within the control even if value did not change (touching the same selected value). Have you had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ValueChanged action for detecting the the switch of segments.

Is `selectedSegment` your `UISegmentedControl`?

Then you code should be like:

```
- (IBAction) segmentSwitch:(id)sender {
    if (self.selectedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard; 
    } else{
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but right now it doesnt even go into the segmentedSwitch method. Meaning my NSLog command is not printed which means its not even in there?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have selected the right method `ValueChanged` and also you have connected the outlet of your method properly.

The only thing you need to do now is to replace your code with your code.

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(UISegmentedControl *)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"inside segmented switch");
    NSLog(@"selected segment %d",sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
    {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard; 

    }
    else
    {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid; 
    }
}
```

Try replacing this code with your code.

Hope this helps you.